# Angular App deployed on salesforce - login with community user

Tags: community, session, angular

I have an angular2 app deployed on a salesforce environment(Developers Edition).

I am developing a front end UI to call custom apex rest api's using community users (Community Login User). I have used the session_id after the salesforce community login and passing the sessionId whenever calling a rest endpoint, however I have the following error:

> *"message": "This session is not valid for use with the REST API","errorCode": "INVALID_SESSION_ID"*

I have already enabled API access on the community user however can't access the API's.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How are you fetching session Id?

Comment: fetching it from my angular2 code from the cookie (sid) and calling the rest server as a Bearer token Authorization: Bearer xXXXXXx

Comment: Is this a VF page? Lightning Component? Does that sid you are getting match the one you get if you use the $Api global variable? `{!$Api.Session_ID}`

Comment: Its a visual force page as a container for the angular code.

Comment: also i had a check the API.Session_ID does NOT match the sid cookie

Comment: took that API.Session_ID and was able to successfuly hit the api using postman. How can i acesss API.Session_ID in my angular code?

Comment: I haven't messed with Angular2. But you could just declare a global var in .js somewhere and use that variable to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript declare a global variable somewhere:

```
var sessId = "{!$API.Session_Id}";
```

Then use that variable in your Angular2 App.

Comment: i tried to write a simple script to add the sessionID to a cookie `<script type="text/javascript">
    document.cookie = "session_id=" + {!$Api.Session_ID};
</script>` but got an error document.cookie not found. Any ideas why?

Comment: I also tried to create a controller class to set the session id from UserInfo.getSessionId() but that gives a different value for the session id than Api.Session_Id does. How can i access the API.Session_ID from inside a controller?

Comment: forgot the quotes!